# Jquery PHP how to check if checkbox had already been checked after submitting a form

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checked

I have a dropdown menu where users have to choose an option. Should the option not be listed there, then the user can check a checkbox which, at the same time, disables the dropdown menu and enables the textbox. By this way the user can write his option that is not listed in the menu.
That works fine.
However, if the users check the box to type another option and press submit and, let's say, other things in the form (validation) are wrong causing the system to return to the form, if the user had already checked the box, it should now appear as it was: the dropdown menu disabled and the textbox enabled with its content that the user had typed. I have managed to keep this information with PHP, but the problem is that, even though the checkbox appears checked, the dropdown menu is enabled and the textbox is not.

How can i fix this???

Well, i have got what i want this script to do by using only javascript. However, i would like to know how i can achieve this with jQuery. Does anyone out there know??

meanwhile, here is my code which is working fine:

```
<?php   //checkbox2.php   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?> <html> <head> <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="es"> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> <meta name="generator" content="PhpED Version 7.0 (Build 7043)"> <title>checkbox enable disable</title> <meta name="author" content="Pathros Ibarra">
    <!-- Aqu? va la declaraci?n del script enable textbox when checkbox is checked-->    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        function codename() 
        {
            if(document.forma_registro.checkboxname.checked)
            {
                document.forma_registro.grado_otro.disabled=false;
                document.forma_registro.grado.disabled=true;
            }

            else
            {
                document.forma_registro.grado_otro.disabled=true;     //textname
                document.forma_registro.grado.disabled=false;         //box
            }
        }

        //------------------------- en caso de que se haya escrito texto alternativo, entonces apl?quese la siguiente funci?n
        function codename2() 
        {
            if(document.forma_registro.checkboxname2.checked)
            {
                document.forma_registro.grado_otro2.disabled=false;
                document.forma_registro.grado2.disabled=true;
            }

            else
            {
                document.forma_registro.grado_otro2.disabled=true;
                document.forma_registro.grado2.disabled=false;
            }
        }

</SCRIPT> </head> <body> <?php if(empty($_POST)===false) {
    if((isset($_POST['checkboxname2'])===true && $_POST['checkboxname2']=="ON" ))//|| isset($_POST['checkboxname'])===true && $_POST['checkboxname']=="ON")
    {
        //2da forma
        echo '<p style="color: green; font: bold;">Ok in checkbox 2!</p>';
        if(empty($_POST['grado'])===false)
        {
            echo '<p style="color: purple; font: bold;">Se recibió un dato desde el menú y es: "'.$_POST['grado'].'"</p>';
        }
        else if(empty($_POST['grado_otro'])===false)
        {
            echo '<p style="color: purple; font: bold;">Se recibió un dato desde el cuadro de texto alternativo y es: "'.
            $_POST['grado_otro'].'"</p>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<p style="color: red; font: bold;">No data received in checkbox 2.</p>';
        } ?> <p style="color: green; text-decoration: blink; font: bold;"></p> <h4 style="color: blue;">Forma de ejemplo con checked</h4> <form action="" name="forma_registro" method="post"> <select name="grado2" <?php if(isset($_POST['grado_otro2'])===false) echo 'disabled="disabled"'; ?>> <!-- disabled="disabled" -->   <option value="">--Seleccione--</option>   <option value="volvo" <?php if(isset($_POST['grado2'])===true && $_POST['grado2']=='volvo') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Volvo</option>   <option value="saab" <?php if(isset($_POST['grado2'])===true && $_POST['grado2']=='saab') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Saab</option>   <option value="mercedes" <?php if(isset($_POST['grado2'])===true && $_POST['grado2']=='mercedes') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Mercedes</option>   <option value="audi" <?php if(isset($_POST['grado2'])===true && $_POST['grado2']=='audi') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Audi</option> </select>                <!-- aquí abajo iba el 2 --> <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname2" onclick="codename2()" <?php if(isset($_POST['grado_otro'])===true) echo 'value="ON" checked="checked"'; ?>> Seleccionar si otro: <input type="text" name="grado_otro" <?php if(isset($_POST['grado_otro'])===true) echo 'value="'.$_POST['grado_otro'].'"'; ?>><br> <input type="submit" value="enviar">  </form> <?php

    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<p style="color: green; font: bold;">Ok in checkbox 1 uno!</p>';
        if(empty($_POST['grado'])===false)
        {
            echo '<p style="color: green; font: bold;">Se recibió un dato desde el menú y es: "'.$_POST['grado'].'"</p>';
        }
        else if(empty($_POST['grado_otro'])===false)
        {
            echo '<p style="color: green; font: bold;">Se recibió un dato desde el cuadro de texto alternativo y es: "'.
            $_POST['grado_otro'].'"</p>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<p style="color: orange; font: bold;">No data received in checkbox 1.</p>';
        }
     ?> <p style="color: green; text-decoration: blink; font: bold;"></p> <h4 style="color: blue;">Forma de ejemplo sin checked</h4> <form action="" name="forma_registro" method="post"> <select name="grado" <?php if(isset($_POST['grado_otro'])===true) echo 'disabled="disabled"'; ?>>   <option value="">--Seleccione--</option>  <option value="volvo" <?php if(isset($_POST['grado'])===true && $_POST['grado']=='volvo') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Volvo</option>   <option value="saab" <?php if(isset($_POST['grado'])===true && $_POST['grado']=='saab') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Saab</option>   <option value="mercedes" <?php if(isset($_POST['grado'])===true && $_POST['grado']=='mercedes') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Mercedes</option>   <option value="audi" <?php if(isset($_POST['grado'])===true && $_POST['grado']=='audi') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Audi</option> </select> <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" onclick="codename()" value="ON" <?php if(isset($_POST['grado_otro'])===true) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>> Seleccionar si otro: <input type="text" name="grado_otro" <?php if(isset($_POST['grado_otro'])===false) echo 'disabled="disabled"'; ?> <?php if(isset($_POST['grado_otro'])===true) echo 'value="'.$_POST['grado_otro'].'"'; ?>><br> <input type="submit" value="enviar">  </form>

<!-- Si la forma del checkbox está en ON, entonces aplicará lo sig: if($_POST['checkboxname2']=="ON" || $_POST['checkboxname']=="ON") y con otra forma y el checkboxname2()  --> <?php
    }//fin del else }//fin del empty post     else {                                     ?> <h4 style="color: blue;">Forma de ejemplo sin checked (inicio)</h4> <form action="" name="forma_registro" method="post"> <select name="grado">   <option value="">--Seleccione--</option>   <option value="volvo" <?php if(isset($_POST['grado'])===true && $_POST['grado']=='volvo') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Volvo</option>   <option value="saab" <?php if(isset($_POST['grado'])===true && $_POST['grado']=='saab') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Saab</option>   <option value="mercedes" <?php if(isset($_POST['grado'])===true && $_POST['grado']=='mercedes') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Mercedes</option>   <option value="audi" <?php if(isset($_POST['grado'])===true && $_POST['grado']=='audi') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Audi</option> </select> <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" onclick="codename()" value="ON"> Seleccionar si otro: <input type="text" name="grado_otro" disabled="disabled" <?php if(isset($_POST['grado_otro'])===true) echo 'value="'.$_POST['grado_otro'].'"'; ?>><br> <input type="submit" value="enviar">  </form>

<?php } ?> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Could you please format your code? You seem to have put all of your HTML in a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple:

```
$('#checkboxname').click(function() {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#grado_otro").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#grado").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $("#grado_otro").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#grado").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});​
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/tmubp/)**

**UPDATE**

Here's one more simple version you can try:

```
$('#checkboxname').click(function () {
    $("#grado_otro").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
    $("#grado").prop("disabled", this.checked);
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tmubp/22/)